# Delete image on GCP - not working via UI nor via gcloud cli

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-container-registry

I am an owner of a project in GCP in which there I currently only one image in my Container Registry.  I am trying to delete it but it shows that I have no permission to do that.
[image]

Any idea why is that?

When trying to run the delete with `gcloud` I am getting a validation error:

[image]

Comment: it is just someone else's computer. how could you believe you own it.

Comment: I am the owner of the project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential reason is that you're impacted by the current opened issue on Container Registry. It's impossible to delete an image via the Console UI.

See below message from GCP:

> Project owners and editors are currently unable to edit tags or delete
>   images in the Container Registry UI. The workarounds are to either use
>   the command line or grant the Storage Object Viewer IAM role. A fix is
>   expected by December 5th.

[image]

In this case, workaround is to delete the image with `gcloud` command line :

```
gcloud container images delete gcr.io/...
```

Be careful here not to confuse with `gcloud compute images` which permits to manage VMs images on Google Cloud Compute.

Comment: I tried that as well but I am getting some strange about the format of the image (regex validation)

Comment: Could you give more details please. What is the error received from command line ?

Comment: Flavo,  yes I am running: `gcloud compute images delete eu.gcr.io/my-project/myimage:1.0.7`  

and getting:  
`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/myimage:1.0.7'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}'`

Comment: The command is `gcloud container images delete [IMAGE]`. and not `gcloud compute images delete`. You should replace `compute` by `container`. The command `gcloud compute images` is for VM images not container in Container Registry.